# how to run a single statement async with return value and support to abort

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I've a single statement running on WPF application
that takes a long time (by long I mean 5000ms , which is too long )
i need to run this statement in thread but ,
i need this thread return bool value indicate status
if it successfully execute it return true
else for Exception  or i forced to stop this single statement return false

What is the best way to accomplish this?
and again it single statement 
and how to safety abort "force to end execute statement "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have some luck taking a look at the [`System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) class. Creating it simply means passing it a [`Func<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) object, so it can be one statement or many. It can handle a return value (that's the difference between it and [`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)). You can also use a [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) to handle a forced stop. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx) for more on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can acomplish that with a background worker. The worker can also report the progress (with events) and have an oncomplete function which you can pass the result too.

For a good guide to it:

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker